# AI for line of block game in java

Tags: java

I am trying to create a classical 3*3 board game.

this is two player game & looks like http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=34o4mjp&s=5 and is very easy to play. the wining condition is somehow like that of tic-tac-toe. actually  i even don't know the exact name of that game but i played it in school when i was child. I named it as line of block.

in this game players has 3 blocks each. Each player can move one block at time in his/her turn. finally the one who will able to make line of block either diagonally or horizontally or vertically except his/her own side will be winner. 
I have coded this game for two player in java but i am getting problem with AI.

can any one suggest me which AI algorithm can i use for this game? what is the exact name of this game?

i searched AI algorithm for two player and found that minimax algorithm can be implemented but i am not getting how to implement minimax in my case.

Answer (score 2):

The minimax here is a way to go
This kind of games belongs to a category of 2-player games with full information, so minimax is a classical solution here. You can consider also a technique called "alpha-beta pruning" for optimization.

It doesn't differ much from classical tic-tac-toe, actually.
All you need is to find a good heuristic function that will estimate your current state.
The strength of your AI program will depend on your heuristic function.
All the rest is as a classical minimax algorithm implementation.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Another poster suggested Minimax, and yes, that is a classic solution for board games like this. In this case, though, it is completely unnecessary. There are only 1680 possible board states for this game (x2 for the 2 players whose turn it can be), so you can easily do a brute-force search of the game tree and "solve" it.

You could do this at run time, or else first pre-calculate the "perfect" move for every possible board state, store them in a table, and just do a table lookup at run time.

Comment: Minimax is more appropriate for games like chess -- I just calculated that there are 4634726695587809641192045982323285670400000 possible permutations of a set of chess pieces on a chess board, so brute force is clearly unfeasible.